# Reading iOS light sensor with ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit, light-sensor

Is there a way to access the ambient light sensor of an iOS device, using the ARKit, without using the AR at all?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2878308-ambientintensity

In other words, can I access the value of "ambientIntensity" without creating an AR scene.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the docs for `ARLightEstimate.ambientIntensity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arlightestimate/2878308-ambientintensity):

> This value is based on the internal exposure compensation of the camera device

In other words, if you want to use the device camera to estimate local lighting conditions and aren't otherwise using ARKit, you might be better off using the [camera APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture). (For one thing, those APIs are available on all iOS 11 devices and several earlier iOS versions, rather than needing the steep OS/hardware requirements of ARKit.)

A quick tour of what you'll need to do there:

1. Set up an `AVCaptureSession` and choose the camera `AVCaptureDevice` 
   that you want. You may or may not need to wire up a video/photo capture output (which in your case will be mostly unused).
2. Start running the capture session.
3. Use KVO to monitor the exposure, temperature, and/or white balance related properties on `AVCaptureDevice`.

You can find (older, ObjC) code covering all this (and a lot more, so you'll need to extract the parts that are relevant to you) in Apple's [AVCamManual sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014578).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `ARSCNView` but you do need to have a running `ARSession` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession

Once you have that set up you can call `currentFrame` which will give you an `ARFrame` which has a `lightEstimate` property which contains the `ambientIntensity` estimate.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it works (even if the value is a bit weird).
I used 
`self.arConfig = [ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration new];
self.arConfig.lightEstimationEnabled = YES;`
And I set the permission for using the camera.

Comment: Sadly it seems that it's not possible to use it with the front camera, which I need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the captureOutput function to override when adapting the Protocol AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

```
override func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        //Retrieving EXIF data of camara frame buffer
        let rawMetadata = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(allocator: nil, target: sampleBuffer, attachmentMode: kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
        let metadata = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, rawMetadata) as NSMutableDictionary
        let exifData = metadata.value(forKey: "{Exif}") as? NSMutableDictionary
        
        if let light = exifData?[kCGImagePropertyExifBrightnessValue] as? NSNumber {
            print("Light \(light.floatValue)")
        } else {
            print("problem with light")
        }
}
```